# Changing the menu icon-color/icon in Android Easy Share Action

Tags: android, android-sharing

I am trying to implement Easy Share Action for my Android application as describe in [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html). I was able to complete it successfully. But I need to change the Sharing Menu Item icon color or even icon. According to the given document we don't provide any icon in *drawable* folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Action Bar Icon Pack from [here](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html), locate the sharing icon you want whether holo light or dark.

For instance if you use holo light, the share icon is located in `\Action Bar Icons\holo_light\01_core_share`.

Should be easy to change the color of the drawables and copy to `/res` folder of your project.

Comment: But in the menu, we are not pointing to a drawable. I placed those icons anyway but haven't changed it.

Comment: Just do: android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share" in the menu xml after copying